# SQL Table Appearing in Random Order

Tags: sql-server, ssms

How can a make the tables / views appear in alphabetical order on a SQL Server?

The Tables and Views in my SQL Server are appearing in a random order, not alphabetically or by schema as shown.

[image: SQL Studio appearance]

The tables/views appear like this in SQL Studio, Visual Studio and Azure Data Studio, which would suggest it's a setting on the actual server.

Comment: Looks like it is using a collation that sorts upper case before lower case

Comment: So far from random, if you spend a little time looking at it.

Comment: You do well to remake the whole server, case sensitive collations are hell

Answer (score 0):

Martin Smith was right the collation is Latin1_general_bin. Thanks

Damien_The_Unbeliever, they do appear a lot more random on the full view partially when there are loads of different schemas in the db  (this was a simplified example) .... but yeah, you're right they aren't random, just look that way when there's hundreds of tables.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).